# Car reservation with mongoose and references

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new to mongoDB and i am building a reservation system with cars. What i am trying to do is to get the cars which are not reserved. The user give the dates he wants to rent the car and i must show him the available ones.

Can i do this with one query? I've done this with MySql but i am confused with mongoose..

I have this Car model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const carSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    brand: String,
    model: String,
    power: String,
    seats: Number,
    imgUrl: String,

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);
```

And this reservation model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const reservationSchema = Schema({
        car_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Car' },
        from: Date,
        until: Date,
    });


    module.exports = mongoose.model('Reservation', reservationSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reservation will have many cars, so your `reservationSchema` should be:

```
const reservationSchema = Schema({
        car:[ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'cars' }],
        from: Date,
        until: Date,
    });
```

Consider another model: `availableCarSchema`. All cars are here. When a car is resrved, it is removed from this document, and when the reservation ends, the car is added back to this document.
So to find available cars, you'd query `availableCars` like this:

`AvailableCars.find({brand:'preferred brand',model:'preferred model',other propertis})`